# xpath: math with elements containing a '-' in their name (<node-name>)

Tags: xpath, subtraction

I'd like to do some math with some elements which contain a `-` in their name:

```
<containers>
  <container>
    <max-capacity>10</max-capacity>
    <content>5</content>
  </container>
  <container>
    <max-capacity>10</max-capacity>
    <content>8</content>
  </container>
</containers>
```

I'd like to execute an xpath query which counts the number of containers having a remaining capacity of > 2

```
count(containers/container[max-capacity-content>2])
```

but since there is a `-` in the name of the node `max-capacity` this doesn't work.

What do I have to do to make this work?

(I don't want to transform the xml to a `-`-free document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add spaces - `containers/container[max-capacity - content > 2]` works according to http://www.xpathtester.com/test, and should work within a `count()` expression such as yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

> since there is a - in the name of the node `max-capacity` this doesn't
>   work.
>
> What do I have to do to make this work?
>
> (I don't want to transform the xml to a --free document.)

**Your problem isn't that you have names like `max-capacity`** -- the problem is that by not separating a name and the `-` operator with white space, you are creating a new name: `max-capacity-content` and there is no element with that name in the XML document.

**Solution**:

```
 count(containers/container[max-capacity - content > 2])
```